# Setting up a rails model association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

My rails app has a user model that has a HABTM relationship with interests and holidays. Both of these (interests and holidays) only have one attribute that needs to be edited and related to the user. This is setup and working fine.

I need to create a new model called friend_birthday thats contains information regarding the birthdays of the users friends (and their respective interests). This model (friend_birthday) needs to have several attributes ( :name, :gender, :dob, and :interests).

I was thinking on using a has_many/belongs_to for this one. User has many friends_birthdays and friends_birthdays belongs_to a user.

Does this sound right? How could i implement this?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Have you looked at has_many :through? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this sounds right, but i think it is better to name model Friend

```
class Friend
  belongs_to :user
  #also u can use HABTM for interests, 
  #but it is better to use rich join table and polymorphic association
  has_and_belongs_to_many :interests 
end

class User
  has_many :friends
end
```

Ofc if friends are not users)) just RL friends

Comment: thanks!...what is the best way to approach the rich join table for Friend/interests... Has many => through?

Comment: yes, but if u r not expirienced enough yet, u should use HABM, it is much easier.